# Tesseract auxiliary commands

Tags: tesseract

I installed Tesseract and its basic functionality is fine. But when I try following [this instruction on language file generation](http://succeed-project.eu/wiki/index.php/Tesseract_3.02#Building_a_Tesseract_trained_data_bundle), tesseract-dependent commands like `wordlist2dawg` are "not found" by the shell.

Q: How do I install Tesseract with all these commands available? It's my understanding that they should work once I installed Tesseract, but it isn't the case. I installed Tesseract via `port install tesseract`, might be that I missed something.

Q2: How do I actually train Tesseract? I know it's an opaque topic; most results I get online are 3 years old at best, and it's difficult to figure out the exact training mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build the training tools and then follow the instructions in the page.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract#building-the-training-tools

Comment: Thanks! I followed these instructions, fiddled a bit with environment vars and it worked. On to the training part!